# Match Condition Multiple Criteria

Tags: google-sheets, gs-conditional-formatting

In [this](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1YqAcCvR9ECnX3IuHh7xw3eioLeHBber2K0SFh_GVdis/edit?usp=sharing) Google Sheet In the 'Omnichannel Needs' tab, the data value in column 'File Name' can have a Status of "Studio Done" or "Studio in Progress" which have a corresponding colour format.

I need to achieve the following in the 'Comps' tab:

In the range B5:K10 if the same file name exists in the column 'File Name' in 'Omnichannel Needs' tab, apply the colour formatting from 'Status' column in 'Omnichannel Needs' tab.

Example: B5 in 'Comps' should be yellow as it has a "Studio in Progress" value.

I got the conditional formatting to only work by checking if the 'file name' is there, however I need to add the second condition of getting its status and then apply the status colour.

Comment: since it's just an example sheet, could you provide us access to also edit the sheet?

Comment: @DanielSouza sorry about that. I have updated to edit access now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can change the order of the columns in 'Omnichannel Needs', you could use `match` with `vlookup` (The reference column must be before the data column for vlookup to work).  You can create two conditional formats with the different colors and the following base formula:  `=match(VLOOKUP(B5,indirect("Omnichannel Needs!$E$2:$F"),2,False),"Studio Done")`.

[image: image1]

Here I've added a copy of the 'Status' column AFTER the 'File Name' column to allow `vlookup` to work.

[image: image2]

Comment: Sorry all.  I unfortunately deleted the images from Imgur.  The conditional formatting is visible in the example sheet linked from the OP.